# Unable to Input Chinese Characters Using Pinyin

Tags: language-support, ibus, input-language, input-method, chinese

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04, and I'm trying to input Chinese characters using `ibus` and/or `ibus-pinyin`. The problem I face is that, no matter what input methods I try to switch to, I never see the expected pop-up window with suggested characters.

**Some things I've tried:**

- Running `ibus-daemon -r`
- Adding `export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus`, etc. to my `.bashrc` (as suggested by ibus)
- And more... I can answer any questions to the best of my ability in comments on this post/edits to the post, if it's helpful.

**Results of Various Commands**

Running `ps aux | grep ibus` outputs:

```
charles    22728  0.0  0.0  12168  2432 pts/1    S+   18:14   0:00 grep --color=auto ibus
```

Running `env | grep -E 'XMOD|_IM'` outputs:

```
GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus

XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus

CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=fcitx

QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
```

Running `env | grep -i type` outputs:

```
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland
```

Running `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` outputs:

```
@a(ss) []
```

Comment: The output of those commands is confusing. Are you really using Ubuntu 22.04, or are you maybe using one of the flavors? Kubuntu?

Comment: Actually I suspect that you run into https://bugs.debian.org/1052005 .